# How can you link a checkbox checked state to a particular cell in excel when using VSTO?

Tags: winforms, excel, vsto, excel-2013

Excel provides you with a checkbox control that you can use a property called "Cell Link" to define which cell the checked property for the particular checkbox is linked to.

When using VSTO, I'd like to do the same, but unfortunately I can't put in an Excel Checkbox control and have to use a Windows Forms checkbox control. This doesn't contain the same "Cell Link" property with which I could bind to a particular range.

Any idea how I could achieve the same thing in VSTO?